# How to get web service api for vonage phone for android platform?

Tags: android, web-services, voip

I am developing call forwarding application in android for vonage phone.  how to get the api's for forwarding calls via android .The [vonage.com](http://www.vonage.com) does not specify any api's for android in their website.Is there any way i could get the api or use their web service?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is as of Feb 2013 covering

1. Authentication
2. Click To Call Web Service Account Directory Web
3. Service Extension Information Web Service Call History Web Service
4. Live Status Web Service Call
5. Recording Web Service Conference Bridge
6. Information Web Service Call
7. Queue Information Web Service

http://businesssupport.vonage.com/ci/fattach/get/2776/0/filename/API+Guide+VBS+01282015.pdf